# Create an empty netCDF4 char variable using python xarray

Tags: python, char, netcdf, python-xarray

I would like to create a netCDF file which stores several variables and their associated coordinates, as well as an empty char variable that can be used to store a variety of projection metadata.

I have tried this:

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

#example variable
A=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

#example coords
x=np.array([10,20])
y=np.array([30,40])

#example netcdf creation with xarray
data_vars={'A':(['y','x'],A),
           'projection':np.str()}
coords={'x':x,
        'y':y}
dataset = xr.Dataset(data_vars=data_vars, coords=coords)
dataset['projection'].attrs['EPSG']='3413'

dataset.to_netcdf('path/to/file.nc')
```

This approach saves the 'projection' variable as type char, but it also assigns an empty string to it:

```
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:     (x: 2, y: 2)
Coordinates:
  * y           (y) int64 30 40
  * x           (x) int64 10 20
Data variables:
    A           (y, x) int64 1 2 3 4
    projection  |S1 ''
```

Using xarray, how can I create the 'projection' variable in such a way that it is simply an empty storage variable, of type char (here represented as |S1), and with no dimensions?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR: I don't have the reputation to comment yet, and could only partly solve the issue, because `to_netcdf` forcibly assigns dimensions to variables.*

I have gotten a bit further with this problem (same issue, setting a variable for the CRS):

```py
data_vars = {
    'A':(['y','x'],A),
    'crs': np.array(b'', dtype='|S1')
}
```

With `|S1` being the numpy datatype for a single byte string. Its use is [discouraged](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html?highlight=strings#string-dtype-note) in Python 3, but it appears that a netCDF that has had its CRS set using GDAL is read by `xarray.open_dataset` in exactly that fashion, so I tried copying that. When writing back out using `to_netcdf`, all seems fine - but `ncdump -h` shows me that my crs variable is assigned a previously inexistent dimension `string1`:

```
$ ncdump -h impact.nc                                                                                                             
[truncated]
    char crs(string1) ;
        crs:inverse_flattening = 298.257223563 ;
        crs:spatial_ref = "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS…"
[truncated]
```

I think I'll <strike>solve</strike>hack around the problem by simply calling `gdal_translate` from Python to add a CRS.